# Criteria and process to introduce new tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags

During review I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11611458) edit. The only change was to introduce a new tag: [evaluation-measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation-measure).

This tag has been used only once before, which was an edit by the same user. The tag has no page describing the meaning. I only see usage in questions which are of the form:

> What measure should I use to ...

which are very likely to be closed anyhow or to be moved to as Stack Exchange pages like Datascience(?) or Statistics(?). The tag seems to be an umbrella tag for more specific tags like [precision-recall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precision-recall), [roc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roc), ...

So I'm wondering:

1. Should I reject the edit?
2. Should I try to fill the new tag page with content?

I'm feeling a bit confirmed by the fact that the user has, based on his tags, only little activity in this area.

Comment: You probably know better than most anybody here, do what you think is right.

Comment: Concerning the description of the tag: the description is pending review, see http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11611349  and http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11611348

Comment: Concerning the usefulness of the tag, I think it is useful and I tried to describe it on its page, which is pending the review :-)

Comment: I agree that the question would better suite to some other SE page, but the tag alone is not useless, similar tags like precision-recall, roc, ... already exist on SO.

Comment: @dedek : First I'm happy that you participate in this discussion. This question shows that this was a borderline case to me. There were just several things confusing me (a) I can not come up with a question which deserves this tag (and not one of the more specifics), which I wouldn't close on SO (b)  I haven't heard this term and  checked my Machine Learning/Statistics bookshelf and couldn't find it (c) couldn't find this or a similar tag on CrossValidated or Data Science. So I would really like to read an answer why this tag is useful on SO as discussed in the answer by Maroun Maroun.

Answer (score 8):

> should I reject the edit

Yes, this tag is not helpful and shouldn't be there.

> should I try to fill the new tag page with content(?)

Since the tag shouldn't exist, there's no point of editing its content.

---

I removed the tag from that question, and since no more questions have it, it'll be removed soon.

Comment: Why is the tag not helpful?

Comment: @dedek "Why is the tag helpful?" might be a more interesting question.

Comment: @Braiam: Where can I answer that question?

Comment: @dedek in [meta]?

Comment: @Braiam Do you mean to create the question and answer on [meta]? OK, I will think about it.

Comment: @dedek If you think it *is* helpful, you can answer OP's question here. I'm quoting OP: "*Should I reject the edit?*" - answering no gives you the opportunity to tell why it's helpful.

Comment: @Braiam: Well, when I look on the edit again, I'm not 100% sure **the edit** was really helpful. The tag is not very important in this case. Sorry to say that, I should think about it longer...

Comment: @MarounMaroun: actually I think you answered here in the comments, the  question on what I should have done in such a situation:
  (a) Make a [meta] is tag XY useful (b) invite the tag creator to contribute.

Comment: @dedek I'd suggest you take a look at the commonly-referenced criteria for burniation (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/216398). They're pretty good criteria for adding new tags (even if that isn't their original intent). If you think your new tag meets at least a few of those points, add an answer here to justify it (particularly since this question became a super-small-scale burniation request!)